# i want to set count for my task by using tasks.length

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

i want to set count for my task like when i added a task it shows me the number and when i remove task it decrement the number i used [count, setCount] but i want to do it with task length if i am doing task.text.length its give me the lenth of digits of task not taking task as an object cani do it with map or what kindly check out my code adn suggest what should i do.

```
 import React, { useReducer, useState } from 'react';
import uuid from 'react-uuid';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';

const AddTasks = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(null);
    const [task, setTask] = useState('');
    const [editing, setEditing] = useState(false);
    const [currentTask, setCurrentTask] = useState({});
    const tasks = useSelector(state => state.tasks);
    const [count, setCount]= useState(0);
    const Increment = () => { setCount(count +1)};
    const completeTask = (id) => {
        console.log(tasks);
        const payload = { id: id, text: tasks[id].text, completed: true }
        dispatch({ type: 'COMPLETE_TASK', payload })
    }

    const removeTask = (id) => {
        dispatch({ type: 'REMOVE_TASK', id: id })
    }

    const editTask = (task) => {
        setSelectedDate(null);
        console.log(task);
        setEditing(true);
        setCurrentTask(task);
    }

    const saveTask = () => {
        setEditing(false);
        console.log(currentTask);
        const payload = { id: currentTask.id, text: currentTask.text, completed: false, addedAt: currentTask.addedAt }
        console.log(payload);
        dispatch({ type: "ADD_TASKS", payload });
    }

    const addTask = () => {
        console.log(selectedDate);
        const payload = { id: uuid(), text: task, completed: false, addedAt: selectedDate }
        dispatch({ type: "ADD_TASKS", payload });
        setTask('');
        setSelectedDate(null);
    }

    return (

        <div className="App-header">

            <form
                onSubmit={e => {
                    e.preventDefault(e.target.value);
                    addTask();

                }}>
                <input
                    className="input-group-prepend"
                    value={task} placeholder="Enter your Task"
                    onChange={e => setTask(e.target.value)}
                />
                <DatePicker
                    className="input-group-prepend"
                    placeholderText="Enter task date "
                    selected={selectedDate}
                    onChange={(date) => setSelectedDate(date)}
                    showTimeSelect
                    timeFormat="HH:mm"
                    timeIntervals={15}
                    timeCaption="time"
                    dateFormat="MMMM d, yyyy H:mm aa"
                /><br />
                <input className="btn btn-primary" type='submit' value='Submit' onClick={()=>{Increment()}} />
            <h3>{count}</h3>
            </form>
            {Object.values(tasks).map((task, index) => (

                <ul  >
                    <li
                        index={index}
                        key={task.id}

                        style={{
                            textDecoration: !task.completed ? 'inherit' : 'line-through'
                        }}

                    >
                        <div>
                            {
                                !task.completed ? <p></p> : <p className="alert alert-danger" >Task Completed </p>
                            }

                        </div>


                        <div className={"container", "border"}>
                            {editing ?
                                <div>
                                    <input type='text' onChange={e => setCurrentTask({ ...currentTask, text: e.target.value })} value={currentTask.text} />

                                    <DatePicker
                                        className="input-group-prepend"
                                        placeholderText="Enter task date "
                                        selected={currentTask.addedAt}
                                        onChange={(date) => setCurrentTask({ ...currentTask, addedAt: date })}
                                        showTimeSelect
                                        timeFormat="HH:mm"
                                        timeIntervals={15}
                                        timeCaption="time"
                                        dateFormat="MMMM d, yyyy H:mm aa"
                                    />
                                </div>
                                :
```

> want to show the number of task here in  tag .

```
                                <div>
                                    <h1> {task.text}</h1>
                                    <p>{task.addedAt.toString()}</p>
                                </div>
                            }

                            {editing ?
                                <div>
                                    <input type='button' className='btn btn-primary' onClick={() => saveTask(task.id)} value='Save Task' />
                                    <input type='button' className='btn btn-link' onClick={() => setEditing(false)} value='Cancel' />
                                </div>

                                :
                                <div>
                                    <input class="btn btn-info" type='button' value='CompleteTask' onClick={() => completeTask(task.id)} /><br />
                                    <input class="btn btn-danger" type='button' value='Remove Task' onClick={() => removeTask(task.id)} /><br />
                                    <input type='button' className='btn btn-primary' onClick={() => editTask(task)} value='Edit Task' />
                                </div>

                            }

                        </div>

                    </li>
                    {task.task}

                </ul>

            ))}
        </div>

    );
};
export default AddTasks;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form onSubmit={e => {
                    e.preventDefault(e.target.value);
                    addTask();

                }}>
  <input className="btn btn-primary" type='submit' value='Submit' onClick={()= 
  {Increment()}} />
</form>
```

It would be better to refactor this to single `onSubmit` function and handle everything there.

```js
const onSubmit = (event) => {
 const {target: {value} } = event;
 event.preventDefault(value);
 addTask();
}

const addTask = () => {

  const payload = {
    id: uuid(),
    text: task,
    completed: false,
    addedAt: selectedDate
  }

  dispatch({ type: "ADD_TASKS", payload });
  setTask('');
  setSelectedDate(null);
}
```

Also you can get number of tasks in a object following way

I assume `tasks` object has a structure of

```
{
  id1: {
    id: ...,
    text: ...,
    ...
  },
  id2: {
    id: ...,
    text: ...,
    ...
  }
}
```

```js
const tasks = useSelector(state => state.tasks);
const [count, setCount]= useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
  setCount(tasks && Object.keys(tasks).length || 0);
}, [tasks])
```

Answer (score 0):

bay taking tasks value as an object and take its lenth do the work i got it

## {Object.values(tasks).length}